# Using a Lightbox: how to properly get preapprovalkey?

Tags: paypal, lightbox

I'm trying to implement the feature described here https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ in the section "**Setting Up Web Pages to Invoke the Embedded Payment Flow Using a Lightbox**".

The guide says that I need to Call the Pay API operation to obtain a valid pay key.
The problem is that I cannot understand how to properly call that method. I was not able to find any example of the "pay" method calling that just gives me the pay key.

My user, before clicking the "PayPal" button, should be able to specify the amount of desired money to pay and then click the PayPal button. At that point the LightBox should appear and let the user login and pay etc...

Another thing that I don't understand (and the documentation seems inconsitent in this point) is this: how can I ask pre-authorization (and get a pay key) if I still don't know which PayPal user will login and pay?

Answer (score 1):

Do you have a form of some kind that captures the amount your buyers types in? You can use that form value to populate the `receiverList.receiver(0).amount` value you define in your Pay API call.

In the Pay call you do not define the user who is completing the payment but the user receiving the payment.

You may want to try using the Adaptive Payment SDK found here:
http://paypal.github.io/

It doesn't have an example for the buyer entering the amount but that should be the easiest part of this.

Comment: Yes, we need to have a form where the user enters the amoount he wants to top-up on his account.

Comment: I'm referring to this API https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Pay_API_Operation/
The receiver is the one that the API_keys belong to? In that case it's ok.
The workflow I need to use is this one: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/adaptive-payments/integration-guide/APIntro/ in the section "Setting Up Web Pages to Invoke the Embedded Payment Flow Using a Lightbox", that requires me to get a "paykey" before proceding.

Comment: About this library http://paypal.github.io
I cannot use it, as far as I know, because the "pay" method is not part of the new REST API and the LightBox flow that I need to use is only available with the old (non-REST) API. Is this correct?